# Lazy load with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to implement a lazy-load functionality in asp.net MVC4 application. But it is not related to scrolling. The page will load with 10 rows from database. Then it will be loading more rows (10 rows per ajax call) from database until it reaches last row in database. Is there any good tutorial/article about this?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: is it appropriate to use lazy-load in this context?

Comment: @Miller Koijam, I,m new to this concept. Please suggest me the right path.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  you mention adding rows.  Are they going to be seeing more in a table on a button click?  this sounds like paging also so maybe a new set of data?

Comment: @Matt Bodily, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: I have done paging and can show you how to increase a table on button click.  Wondering what result you are trying to get so I can post code that will help

Comment: @SKPaul did you find solution to this problem. I would like to implement the same

Comment: @Saurabh, not yet. Still looking for. If you have got anywhere, please let me know.